# Implement unordered_map, unordered_set, map, set using vectors

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashset, stdmap, stdset

This is more of an intellectual exercise, but are there battle-tested C++ libraries implementing hash map/set (`std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_set`), red-back trees (`std::map`, `std::set`) using `std::vector`s?

Take `std::unordered_set` for instance. My idea is to use 3 vectors, `X` (stores heads of chains), `Y` (stores set elements), `Z` (temporary container).

Roughly speaking, given a set element `12345`,

1. Let `i = X[hash(12345) % X.size()]`. Then `Y[i]` is the head of the chain that `12345` lives on.
2. `Y[i]` is a pair `(val, j)`. `val` is some element value. `Y[j]` is the next item on chain.
3. Once `12345` is found, deleting it can leave a "hole" in `Y`.
4. A new element will be pushed back to `Y` and `X` will be adjusted accordingly.
5. If the number of "holes" in `Y` exceeds, e.g. 50% of `Y.size()`, adjust `X` and `Y` globally to erase all the "holes", during which `Z` might be needed as a temporary storage.

The idea applies to trees in `std::set` and `std::map`. Of course many other details need to be carefully taken care of.

Has anybody tried something like this? The motivation is to keep the data structure as compact as possible, and to avoid memory allocations as much as possible. I imagine this will yield some good speedup for small and medium size applications -- or maybe I am wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Vectors can be used for unordered containers' hash table. But the actual nodes cannot be vectors in order to efficiently use memory and correctly implement iterator invalidation semantics and complexity.

Comment: The unordered containers have requirements that force them to pretty much be a `std::vector<std::list<T>>`.  The ordered containers are RB Tress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are. Google [dense_hash_map](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash) is one of such example.

There is an immense variety of hash maps and tables built with purpose-specific requirements like cache locality, size, read speed, write speed. As speed is highly dependent on cache locality, it is very common for these implementations to use vectors as backend storage.

Have a look at [this shootout between hashmaps](https://github.com/HFTrader/hash-table-shootout) and browse through every one of them.